# Trim string after a certain character sql

Tags: sql

I have a list of places many of the  places not all  have their ID appended at the end of the name of the places they usually starts after the dash character (-). I only need to show the name of the place and not the ID. All the IDs have a length of 5  characters,

i.e :

```
132 rockaway blvd -12345 , 176-58 bayshore avenue -78952, 12-89 rosedale place but I need to only display:
    132 rockaway blvd
    176-58 bayshore avenue
    12-89 rosedale place

I have tried `select distinct right(rtrim(placeName),7) from places` but this only gives me the last characters  -12345
```

Comment: I think you need to use left  SELECT LEFT(placeName, LEN(placeName) - 5) FROM places     --- Assuming you will never have a null value, if there are null values, you'll need to handle that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @table1 as table(column1 varchar(200))
insert into @table1(column1) values('132 rockaway blvd -12345')
insert into @table1(column1) values('176-58 bayshore avenue -78952')
insert into @table1(column1) values('12-89 rosedale place -9999999999')
select 
column1,  left(column1,len(column1)-charindex('-',reverse(column1)))  
from @table1
```

--if you can give me more example I can modify this query